# How to write "trim" function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have written "trim" function like this

```
 IF trim(both P_BEN_AADHAR_NUM) IS NULL THEN
        P_SUC_FLAG := 'F';
        P_ERROR    := 'BENREG004'; --'AADHAR Number cannot be Blank';
      END IF;
```

is this the correct way to write trim function in PostgreSQL.

Comment: "*Correct way*" to achieve what? Does the code you've written work or does it not? If no, what's the input you're trying with, and what is the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your check is based in the assumption that `TRIM()` returns `NULL` when the string only contains white space. That isn't true, it handles `NULL` the standard way so you can only get `NULL` if the column itself is `NULL`:

```
SELECT TRIM('    '), TRIM(NULL);
```

| btrim | btrim |
| --- | --- |
|  | null |

([Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6fa2e7454a95a22a636a7cd31db8c219))

You need to handle both conditions separately:

```
IF P_BEN_AADHAR_NUM IS NULL OR TRIM(P_BEN_AADHAR_NUM) = '' THEN
```

If you really want to make a compact check in a single condiction, you need a function that can handle `NULL` out of the box (`COALESCE()` comes to my mind) but it's up to you to evaluate what's more legible:

```
IF COALESCE(TRIM(P_BEN_AADHAR_NUM), '') = '' THEN
```

Note: I'm dropping `BOTH` because it's the default.